# Brouwer's fixed point theorem on a sphere

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: S^{2} \rightarrow S^{2} $ be a continuous map such that there exists a closed "disk" $D$ that is mapped to itself. Then will $f$ have a fixed point?

Comment: Hint: Is there a fixed point for a continuous map $f:D \to D$?

Comment: The closed "disk" in $S^2$ is just slightly bent compared to the "true" disk, i.e. the two are homeomorphic.